# How to host Kafka behind a proxy/facade/gateway?

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk

I'm working on a project where I need to setup a Kafka server in AWS for our 3rd party (client) to consume the message.
Currently, I'm planning to use the MSK (AWS Kafka) but we are facing some technical issue here. The MSK kafka need to be expose to public network in order for other party to consume from the brokers. However, I don't think we should expose it to public network. The Kafka should be put behind a proxy or gateway.

As per current research, I don't see there is a way to hide the MSK kafka behind a proxy/loadbalancer.

We also thought whether if we can build a facade microservice to be the agent between Kafka and Consumers. We are using SpringBoot as our backend. I was checking if Spring Cloud Stream  can act as a proxy gateway, but I can't find much clue. I also read Spring AMQP can act as a event-drive proxy but it doesn't support the Kafka custom Protocol.

Hence, I'm kind of stuck at here. Does anyone has any idea for above issue? Thanks and appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

There exists two projects on Github to make this possible. `kafka-proxy` uses TCP and REST Proxy by Confluent uses HTTP.

Otherwise, sure, you can always write your own HTTP, gRPC, whatever interface in Spring to forward data into the brokers, but native Kafka protocol will always be faster. Besides, MSK offers IAM authentication, so that should be good enough for protecting the cluster from unauthorized access

FWIW, Confluent Cloud is also public and uses certificates just as would any other public API, so if the creators of Kafka didn't think to add a proxy, I'm not sure what good it would do for you

Comment: Thanks for the info @OneCricketeer. We did thought of using kafka-rest as our 2nd option if there is no available "proxy". I also believed MSK did provide some solid protection to cluster, but our company insist us to add a proxy in between consumer and brokers. I did some reading, and found I can use Spring webflux + reactor kafka to achieve the "proxy" service. I will try on this path for now.

Comment: That's more-or-less the same as the existing REST Proxy solution... It's just an HTTP server. Anything you add will impact scalability and throughput. E.g. if you have one webflux server, and a topic with hundreds of partitions, then you create a single point of failure, and a bottleneck